# Prove of relation between curl and area

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $D(\vec{a},\vec{n},r)$ denote the open disk with centre $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, unit normal $\vec{n}$ and radius $ r>0$. Prove that if $\vec{F}$ is a $C^1$ vector field, then

$$\vec{n} \cdot \text{curl} \vec{F} (\vec{a}) = lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\text{area}(D(\vec{a},\vec{n},r))} \int_{\partial D(\vec{a},\vec{n},r)} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$$

Is it necessary to use a disk here?

I used Stokes' Theorem on the RHS and I need curl$\vec{F}
$ to be independent of $\vec{D}$ to produce area of $(D(\vec{a},\vec{n},r))$ - having trouble with reasoning something that may not be true? Am I making progress?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, $\text{curl}\vec{F}(a)$ doesn't need to be independent of $r$. Since $\vec{F}$ is $C^1$, the error term of approximating $\text{curl}\vec{F}$ by $\text{curl}\vec{F}(a)$  on $\partial D$ vanishes faster than $\text{area}(D(\vec{a},\vec{n},r))$ as $r \to 0$ and doesn't affect the final limit.

Comment: What's the error term?

Comment: The error term is $$\int_{D} \left(\text{curl}\vec{F}(x)-\text{curl}\vec{F}(a)\right) \cdot d \vec{S}(\vec{r})$$ (BTW, I make a typo in my last comment, it is on $D$, not on $\partial D$).

Comment: I may misunderstood the question but does curl$\vec{F}$ imply curl$\vec{F}(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know Stokes' Theorem? If so, take a small disc in $\textbf R^{3}$, of radius $\epsilon $ centered at pt $\textbf p_{0}$ and now Stokes' Theorem says

$\int \int _{D_{\epsilon }}curl\textbf F\cdot \textbf ndA_{D_{\epsilon }}=\int _{\partial D_{\epsilon }}\textbf F\cdot d\textbf r$.

The idea now is to observe that if $\epsilon $ is small then the LHS is approximately curl($\textbf F(\textbf p_{0}))$ times the area of the disc which is $\pi \epsilon ^{2}$.

Thus for small $\epsilon >0$, we have

curl($\textbf F(\textbf p_{0}))\cdot \textbf n\sim \frac{1}{\pi e^{2}}\int _{\partial D_{\epsilon }}\textbf F\cdot d\textbf r$.

Now take the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and you get

curl($\textbf F(\textbf p_{0}))\cdot \textbf n=\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi e^{2}}\int _{\partial D_{\epsilon }}\textbf F\cdot d\textbf r$.

Comment: Can you expand on how you computed the double integral? I got stuck there

Comment: When you applied Stokes' theorem, why is the integral with respect to A of the disk? Why isnt it with respect to the just the disk?

Comment: If you consider $curlF$ to be constant on the small disc, then it factors out of the integral and you are left with calculating "surface area" of a disc, which is just its area, that is $\pi \epsilon {^2}$

Comment: Why do you sub in $p_0$ when you factor it out? What if curlF is not constant?

Comment: The curl is not necessarily constant as you say. BUT, if $\epsilon $ is small, we can replace $F(p)$ by $F(p_{0})$ as an approximation. That's why the second to last expression is not an equality. That the approximation becomes exact in the limit is another issue which of course requires proof and for this you need to slap some conditions on $F$. But usually one simply defines the curl by the last formula, whenever the limit exists.

Comment: Does curl$F$ imply curl $F(p)$? So when $\epsilon$ is small, it approximates to curl$F(p_0)$?

Comment: $curlF$ is a function, $curlF(p)$ is the function evaluated at $p$. When $\epsilon $ is small, the constant function  $G$ defined by $G(p)=curlF(p_{0})$ approximates $curlF$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.